# Remote control with htc evo 3d via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, htc-evo-3d

Can i conect my htc evo 3d to pc via bluetooth, so i can use the remote control feature? i tried unified remote, and it says it supports bluetooth connection, but is ot possible to conect the phone to pc using bluetooth?

It works with usb cable, but i'm interested in something more cableless :).
I'm using android 4.0.3, and the phone is not rooted.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Nicholas! You already found the correct tags for your question. Have you clicked on the "remote-control" tag and checked the questions there? Most likely they already have the answer you are looking for. If not, please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/47759/edit) your question and point out what you've checked, why it doesn't solve your issue, and what you are missing (I miss e.g. the fact what you want to control, i.e. in which direction: PC->phone or phone->PC).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've  solved the given problem.
In fact, it wasn't actually a problem - the application i used had some problems with bluetooth.

I tried setting BT up, and it worked. I was able to send files from my PC to my phone without any problems. On the other hand, the application didn't work - i was unable to control my PC via my phone using BT.

Checking their website i noticed that the BT feature is actually pretty bugy.
(The app is Unified Remote).

Then, just for testing purposes i tried Windows Remote Service, and it worked, without problems.
So, basically, it seems the problem was somewhere in the app. I changed the app and manage to achieve what i needed - to remotely control my PC from my phone.

Just one note - it's recommended you use Windows' default drivers for your BT device. You can use this freeware - bluetoothinstaller.com to install the BT device with MS dfeault drivers.